# Should we make [error] tag as a synonym of [warning-messages] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The word *error* is misleading. In many cases, the message of *Mathematica* only suggests that something **may** be wrong. Will it be better to rename it as [warning-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning-messages), which is also the terminology chosen by the document?

I know in principle I can suggest a synonym [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/warning-messages/synonyms), but currently I don't have enough reputation under this tag.

Comment: Creating a synonym would be my preference.  Someone must have 5 points under `warning-messages`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Now I have enough reputation under [tag:warning-messages], but still, I cannot suggest the synonym, because I mistakenly suggested [tag:warning-messages] as a synonym of [tag:error]… So, guys, some **down**vote please!: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/error/synonyms

Comment: The wording of the "'error' Tag Synonym" page does seem ambiguous.   What did you intend: error as a synonym of warning-message instead of warning-message as a synonym for error?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yeah, in other words, I think [tag:error] should be a [tag:warning-messages] synonym.

Comment: As requested, I have downvoted warning-message as a synonym for error.  I wonder how voting on proposed synonyms is solicited.  I saw nothing about it on the Review page earlier.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yeah, the page isn't in an easy-to-find place. Seems that the creator of SE doesn't want people to play with tags too much?

Comment: OK, the suggestion has been deleted, but I still can't suggest [tag:error] as [tag:warning-messages] synonym, because [tag:warning-messages] has been suggested as a [tag:error-messages] synonym, while [tag:error-messages] has already been a synonym of [tag:error]?! Well, I think this time we really need moderator attention. @J.M.

Comment: Yes, [tag:error] is the main tag, and [tag:error-messages] maps to it. So, should [tag:warning-messages] map to [tag:error] as well?

Comment: @J.M. As mentioned in the question, my suggestion is [tag:error] should map to [tag:warning-messages], but currently we can't even vote to…: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJq6H.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to messy reasons, it seems I would have to do the merge myself, so [error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) and [error-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-messages) are now [warning-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning-messages) synonyms. If any problems came up because of this, please leave a comment.