# What's the difference between [error-messages] and [error-tracking]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Today I changed a tag from [error-tracking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-tracking) to [warning-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning-messages) ([née](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2553/should-we-make-error-tag-as-a-synonym-of-warning-messages-tag) [error-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-messages), [error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error)).  Then I did some looking into them.  Neither [error-tracking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-tracking) or [warning-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning-messages) have tag wikis and both are fairly old.  There are rather few questions tagged [error-tracking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-tracking) (about 85).  A good number (probably less than half, though) are about warning messages.  Some of them are also tagged [warning-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning-messages).  Some are about the warning-message system, sometimes tagged [message-coding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-coding).  Some of the questions are about tracking down programming errors and not about error messages at all.  Some are about detecting error conditions in a running program and responding to them.

Sometimes people don't ask the question in an unambiguous way. For instance, "Why do I get this error?" often means "How do I fix my code to avoid this error?", which is what the tag [warning-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning-messages) is about. Usually the question is not about how to "track" errors.  Honestly, I'm not sure what "error tracking" means on this community. It sounds a bit like "bug tracking," which is closer to [testing-and-verification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing-and-verification), perhaps.  Maybe it's about how to identify and locate errors in code.

Is there difference between [error-tracking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-tracking) and [warning-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warning-messages)?  Is the difference great enough to have two tags?  Can we develop guidelines that distinguish them?  Or should they be synonyms?

Related tags (only the last three have wikis):

- [error-trapping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-trapping)
- [error-propagation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-propagation)
- [message-coding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/message-coding)
- [usage-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage-messages)
- [testing-and-verification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing-and-verification)